# Is there a Chinese phrase equivalent to "difficult to eat"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, phrase, word-requests, phrase-request

I wonder if there is a Chinese word or phrase equivalent to "difficult to eat" or "hard to eat".

For example, someone said that pomegranates and artichokes are among the [19 most hard-to-eat foods](https://www.buzzfeed.com/rachelysanders/foods-that-are-too-damn-hard-to-eat).

I thought it would be "难吃" or "不方便吃", but the former [literally means](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9A%BE%E5%90%83/123902?fr=aladdin) "taste bad" and the latter means "it's not the right time to eat".

石榴很**

I know a long answer: [吃起来不方便](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E5%90%83%E8%B5%B7%E6%9D%A5%E4%B8%8D%E6%96%B9%E4%BE%BF&pn=0&oq=%E5%90%83%E8%B5%B7%E6%9D%A5%E4%B8%8D%E6%96%B9%E4%BE%BF&ie=utf-8&fenlei=256&rsv_idx=1&rsv_pq=bb51edd400c4e244&rsv_t=0c2f%2F5xJDIFgYQpqifVD1oi4GcZTiDNQAqzlx%2FoBoA0CGZeB3RwDFoklLL8). For example, 石榴吃起来不方便。

Is that the best/only expression?

Comment: How about 難以食用 / 難以進食?

Comment: Perhaps, 吃起来费劲 or 吃着费劲.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try: 吃起来很麻烦

I can't agree with the list of hard to eat foods!

Comment: It is a native expression. Here is a Chinese website: [公认吃起来最麻烦的 4 种水果](https://kuaibao.qq.com/s/20190124A19KT400?refer=spider)

Answer (score 1):

无从下口 is a possible idiom in some contexts.

eg. 老虎吃田螺，无从下口

Answer (score 0):

难以食用  also implies the object cannot be eaten or it is almost impossible to eat it (e.g. 难以抵挡  = cannot withstand; 难以置信  = unbelievable)

无从下口 also refers to 'can't interject opinion'

I suggest 食用不便 (inconvenient to eat) or 吃来麻烦 (trouble to eat)

For example, crustaceans with hard shells, fish with fine bones are inconvenient to eat, but not impossible

Answer (score -1):

Yes for example 不好吃  味道一般
These two words are not offensive

Comment: The question is not asking for less offensive expressions.

Comment: I think your answer means "not tasty", not "difficult to eat".